# Spring Aspects: specify which packages to weave

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I have a Spring / Hibernate application. Custom type created by Hibernate needs Spring context, so I use Spring Aspects to provide it.

```
@Configurable(preConstruction = true)
public class EncryptedStringUserType implements EnhancedUserType {
...

@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
public class RootConfiguration {
...
```

After adding Spring Security, I got number of messages in stderr like this:

```
[AppClassLoader@14dad5dc] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
when weaving type org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
```

Is it possible to specify packages of classes that should be weaved and avoid trying to weaving other ones?

### SOLUTION

Put META-INF/aop.xml to resources root and exclude unnecessary packages:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <exclude within="org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.*"/>
        <exclude within="org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.openid.*"/>
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

Comment: Maybe not the answer for your question but seems `@Configuration` missing for `RootConfiguration` class.

Comment: It's loaded to the context straightly, `applicationContext.register(RootConfiguration.class);`, so no need in annotation. Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the scope of weaving by adding a `<include within="your.package.here.*"/>` tag to the `META-INF/aop.xml` file in your classpath.  Here's a full example of `META-INF/aop.xml` taken from the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-first-example):

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>

    <weaver>
        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
        <include within="foo.*"/>
    </weaver>

    <aspects>
        <!-- weave in just this aspect -->
        <aspect name="foo.ProfilingAspect"/>
    </aspects>

</aspectj>
```

Comment: What aspect name should I specify if I want to weave only classes annotated with `@Configurable`?

Comment: I believe this would work: `<include within="@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable foo.*"/>`.  The docs for `META-INF/aop.xml` are here: http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw-configuration.html

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't - I still see these messages.

Comment: @Marboni are you sure that your `aop.xml` is being picked up?  Like if you put invalid content in your `aop.xml`, do you get an error?

Comment: Thank you, @heenenee, you are right. META-INF was not in the resources root. Not it works fine.